bs-datepicker-inline not showing proper design
I'm using bs-datepicker-inline in angular which is rendered like this

Code:

html component

<bs-datepicker-inline id="bsdatepickerinline" [bsConfig]="bsConfig"
                                            [minDate]="minDate" [bsValue]="maxDate"
                                            (bsValueChange)="fromDateSelect($event)"></bs-datepicker-inline>


ts file:

minDate: Date = new Date();
init() {
        this.maxDate = new Date();
        this.maxDate.setDate(this.maxDate.getDate())
        this.bsConfig = Object.assign({}, { dateInputFormat: 'DD-MMM-YYYY', adaptivePosition: true, showWeekNumbers: false });
    }

it is rendered as shown in screenshot but i don't want first row i.e. date 27 to 32
any solution Thanks

showWeekNumbers: false should be enough, make sure this key is present in your bsConfig which you are assigning to <bs-datepicker-inline. when are you calling init fn?

Those are not dates, they are week numbers.
Try initializing the bsConfig object in raw format:
Eg:
bsConfig = { showWeekNumbers : false , ....}

